# How do I build v8 on Windows?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2008, scons, v8

Could someone tell me how to install and build v8 on windows? I am using Windows 7 with VS 2008.

Comment: "Simply can't do it" doesn't give us much to work with.

Comment: https://code.google.com/apis/v8/intro.html ?

Answer (score 3):

The following worked for me in VS2013:

From http://gneu.org/2014/02/integrating-v8/

```
git clone git://github.com/v8/v8.git v8
cd v8
svn co http://gyp.googlecode.com/svn/trunk build/gyp
svn co http://src.chromium.org/svn/trunk/tools/third_party/python_26@89111 third_party/python_26
svn co http://src.chromium.org/svn/trunk/deps/third_party/cygwin@231940 third_party/cygwin
svn co https://src.chromium.org/chrome/trunk/deps/third_party/icu46 third_party/icu
```

Now from [Build googles v8 as shared library on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14916272/build-googles-v8-as-shared-library-on-windows)

```
third_party/python_26/python.exe build\gyp_v8 -Dtarget_arch=ia32 -Dcomponent=shared_library
msbuild /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=Win32 tools\gyp\v8.sln
```