# Build googles v8 as shared library on windows?

Tags: build, v8, gyp

Is it possible to build googles v8 as a shared library with gyp on windows (msvc 2012)? Everything I tried doesn't work. What I've tried:

```
python build\gyp_v8 -Dcomponent=shared_library
python build\gyp_v8 library=shared
```

The second one gives an error that "library" is unknown. The first one does not have any effect.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953413/how-to-actually-build-v8-on-windows

Comment: SCons is outdated... Also, this does not affect my problem.

Comment: AS far as I can see with gyp it is better to use Cygwin but no matter. I see the way to do the option for the shared library is to tweak the GYP_DEFINES variable and not supply it as a command line parameter. From here http://code.google.com/p/v8/wiki/BuildingWithGYP Seems to indicate a section called custom build settings and that indicates that it goes via the envvar and not the command line parameter as you indicate.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried: _python build\gyp_v8 -GYP_DEFINES=shared_ and _python build\gyp_v8 -GYP_DEFINES=shared_library_ but it does not work either.

Comment: No,I mean set the environment variable GYP_DEFINES. Not the command line parameter.

Comment: That does not work too :/ Any further ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This works in a project I'm using:

```
python build\gyp_v8 -Dtarget_arch=ia32 -Dcomponent=shared_library
msbuild /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=Win32 tools\gyp\v8.sln
```

Comment: This outputs the same, a lib file.

Comment: I see v8.lib in build\Release\lib but also v8.dll in build\Release. The lib file is the import library for linking against the DLL. Is that not what you see?

Comment: Wow - it finally works! Thanks! I used the wrong .sln file... the one that is located in build/