# Compile V8 modules in windows

Tags: node.js, v8

I'm trying to compile a module with V8 and Node. I configured it to be dll and downloaded the source code and compiled nodejs with vcbuild.bat.

However, it throws errors like

> Error 2   error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A0005F6) "class v8::Handle __cdecl v8::True(void)" (?True@v8@@$$FYA?AV?$Handle@VBoolean@v8@@@1@XZ) referenced in function "public: static class v8::Handle __cdecl v8::Boolean::New(bool)" (?New@Boolean@v8@@$$FSA?AV?$Handle@VBoolean@v8@@@2@_N@Z)

or

> Error 6   error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A0005FE) "public: class
>   v8::Local __thiscall
>   v8::Object::GetPropertyNames(void)"
>   (?GetPropertyNames@Object@v8@@$$FQAE?AV?$Local@VArray@v8@@@2@XZ)
>   referenced in function "class v8::Handle __cdecl
>   strin(class v8::Arguments const &)"
>   (?strin@@$$FYA?AV?$Handle@VValue@v8@@@v8@@ABVArguments@2@@Z)  c:\Users\aisha\documents\visual
>   studio 2012\Projects\Project2\Project2\EventLog.obj   EventLog

what can be wrong? Seems to be related to the object *HandleScope*

Answer (score 0):

I have built node with v8 dll on Windows (VS2010). I record what I did to share with you all and also for my reference. The packages are fresh clones from git on this day.

First you build v8 as a dll. I used the method BitCortex suggested in this page.
[Build googles v8 as shared library on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14916272/build-googles-v8-as-shared-library-on-windows)

And then

```
0) Suppose you are at the root of the source tree.
1) edit vcbuild.bat (for a debug build)
  Line 15 set config=Release -> set config=Debug
  Line 18 set target_arch=ia32  -> set target_arch=x64
      * target-arch should be the arch of your system.
  Line 92  python configure %debug_arg% %nosnapshot_arg% %noetw_arg% %noperfctr_arg% --dest-cpu=%target_arch% --tag=%TAG%
     ->    python configure %debug_arg% %nosnapshot_arg% %noetw_arg% %noperfctr_arg% --dest-cpu=%target_arch% --tag=%TAG% --shared-v8

2) cp $(v8-dll-build)/include/*h ./src
3) cp $(v8-dll-build)/build/Debug/lib/v8.lib .
4) Build 
   > vcbuild nosign
5) cp $(v8-dll-build)/build/Debug/*.dll Debug
```

That is all there is to it.

Comment: I use Gow bash terminal to copy files so they look like unix command. vcbuild.bat doesn't work on the bash terminal.